# Value (PrivateSubnet2CIDR) for parameter cidrBlock is invalid. This is not a valid CIDR block. This is the error that I am getting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The IP CIDR that I am giving as input seems to be invalid in Cloudformation.
IPs used: VPC(192.168.0.0/16) Subnets-192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.64.0/24,192.168.128.0/24,192.168.192.0/24

I tried manually creating VPC and adding subnets as given above and it worked. But the same doesn't work while giving input in Cloudformation.

Code for parameter and resource:

```
"PublicSubnet1CIDR": {
      "Description": "Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "192.168.0.0/24",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem, in your cloudformation snippet you have the following:

```
"PrivateSubnet1" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties" : {
      "VpcId" : {
        "Ref" : "VPC"
      },
      "CidrBlock" : "PrivateSubnet1CIDR",
      "AvailabilityZone" : {
        "Fn::Select" : [
          "0",
          {
            "Fn::GetAZs" : "ap-south-1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Private Subnet (AZ1)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Notice that for the value of CidrBlock you haven't referenced a parameter, you've just given a plain text value of "PrivateSubnet1CIDR". It should instead look like this:

```
"PrivateSubnet1": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "VpcId": {
        "Ref": "VPC"
      },
      "CidrBlock": {
        "Ref": "PrivateSubnet1CIDR"
      },
      "AvailabilityZone": {
        "Fn::Select": [
          "0",
          {
            "Fn::GetAZs": "ap-south-1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": false,
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "Private Subnet (AZ1)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Note that you need to have a "Ref" for the parameter you are trying to reference, you can't just state the word PrivateSubnet1CIDR.

You have a few other instances of the same issue.

Comment: Tried as per your suggestion but facing the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the parameter section for your parameter called "cidrBlock", and also post the cloudformation script for the resource that's using the value cidrBlock. Even better would be to post your whole cloudformation script.

Comment: Please check if the below file is accessible:

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prakash-1-007/VPC.txt

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please upvote and accept as answer once you've tested.